# Hypernym for "profile" and "preference" in the context of dating or match-making

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

The context is love-matching or match-making.

I am looking for one term/word to address a dating/mating condition that people would have when matching. It's more complicated and thorough than a simple mating condition because we are human so there are many many concerns both we have on others and other people have on us (who we are).

Whatever-the-word-is includes people's own profile (who they are) and people's expections/preferences (who they want). This is *the thing* that I want to address.

I kind of found a word, *benchmark*. But it's just too geeky I guess, and remote. I suppose the first response when people see this word is "what the...".

But to use other words like *preferences, mate conditions* or *match criterion* seems just not quite right.

Comment: Either word works fine. 'Preferences' sounds more lilke what they want (as opposed to who they are, and 'profile' the opposite, but 'profile could include the things they want. 'Benchmark' is not at all the right word, that means a starting point against which you will measure other things later.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider

> ***particulars*** : a specific set of details about or related to a single person or thing.

(Note the definition is mine, since I could not find a suitable definition of the plural noun after a quick search).
This usage is probably a little bit "old-school", but I think it fits perfectly and you could easily revive it when your site becomes popular.